# POSIX threads: the best interruption method

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, c11

The first thing, which I was told when had started working with pthreads, was - you should avoid force thread cancelation, like pthread_cancel. Instead we should use thread cancel notification via threads communication channel.

If we have a really long task to run in the thread, we split this task into small chunks and check the cancelation flag after each chunk processing. Like this:

```
loop {
    process_chunk();
    if (check_cancel_flag())
        break;
}
```

But what is the best approach for implementation of this check_cancel_flag() function?

With all my experience in c and linux, I can remember only those methods:

1. (If you have only one working thread) You can use sig_atomic_t as a type for the cancelation flag. Check it in check_cancel_flag() function and mark it as true in the thread` signal handler. Then just call pthread_kill from the main thread.
2. Use any POD type for cancelation flag and protect it with a mutex. In this case you will get overhead with calling lock too often.
3. Use mutex as cancelation flag. Check it with pthread_mutex_trylock call. If the main thread releases this mutex, it is time to shutdown for the worker thread.
4. (For C11) Use gcc _atomic built-in functions (or another asm atomic library) to set and check cancelation flag.

I could not remember nothing else.

The question: How to choose correct approach?
Do you know any bench mark about this problem?

Comment: There is a [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Condition_variables) discussing the exact question.

Comment: I think it is a bit different, just for comsumer/producer implementation. Indeed, I usie queue and wait conditions, but how to interrupt long task?

Comment: BTW, C11 has simple an `_Atomic` qualification for data types that does the trick. `sig_atomic_t` is never appropriate, its only guarantees are with respect to signal handlers, and there it only guarantees indivisibility, not the other memory consistency properties that you'd want to have.

Comment: I wrote about atomic in C11. I supposed to use sig_atomic_t when we have single working thread and edit it only in signal handler of current thread

Comment: @EugeneSh. That Wiki page is amazing!  Thank you to share.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a reader-writer lock (`pthread_rwlock_t`) to protect the flag, as your worker threads need to frequently read it but it is only written once.

As long as the chunk that is processed in between checks of the flag isn't too small, the overhead will be insignificant.